# How do you position your hand to use the control + w key? What fingers do you use?

Tags: keyboard, keybindings, macvim, mouse-keys

I would like to improve my typing. Currently, I start web dev with vim. I use one of the feature called split, which create new window for me. then we need to hit Control+ W to move around cursors. I find myself vary awkward hit press the control key and w key at the same time, pinky for control key and ring for w key.

I understand there is one correct answer to this question. I would like to know how you guys do it. I definitely will find useful tips to improve the typing overall. Thank you so much in advance.

edit:
Ok, I need to specific, I am using MacbookPro 2016, which only have left control key. (I wish we could modify the right option key to act as a control key, but the left option key stays the same)

Comment: Is this not a primarily opinion based question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Apple Magic keyboard, I use my left thumb for the command key, and my left ring finger for any bottom row keys to the left of that. For command W, I use my thumb and middle finger. For control W I use my ring and middle finger - all on the left hand.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are as many answers as fingers...

If I've got one hand on the mouse, then left hand; ring; middle.

If I've both hands on the keyboard then I'd use the right Ctrl key instead, right hand pinky; left hand, ring.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [karabiner-elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) to remap just the right option key to control.